# Linq to Sql Add and Delete in same transaction

Tags: sql-server, asp.net-mvc, linq, linq-to-sql, transactions

i have an action method for update of master detail record. when data first reaches from view to controller, i select the previous records from db and call delete method of repository.

```
public ActionResult sale(int id, SaleRecord _SaleRecord,int? PositionID)
        {
            SalesRepository _SalesRepository = new SalesRepository();
            if (ModelState.IsValid)
            {
                List<long> prevSaleIDs = _SaleRecord.Items.Where(y => y.ActualSaleID > 0).Select(x => x.ActualSaleID).Distinct().ToList();
                foreach (var SaleID in prevSaleIDs) 
                {
                    var dbData = _SalesRepository.GetSale(SaleID);
                    _SalesRepository.DeleteSaleItems(dbData.mktActualSaleItems.ToList());
                    _SalesRepository.DeleteActualSales(dbData);
                }
-----
-----
}
```

after putting the records for delete i prepare new record by calling updateModel and put it for insert

```
public ActionResult sale(int id, SaleRecord _SaleRecord, int? PositionID)
{
   //as above 
   mktActualSale _Sales = new mktActualSale();
                UpdateModel(_Sales, "_SaleRecord");
                _Sales.mktActualSaleItems.AddRange(_SaleRecord.Items.Where(z => z.SalesQuantity != 0).Select(x => new mktActualSaleItem { SalesQuantity = x.SalesQuantity, SKUID = x.SKUID }));
                _SalesRepository.Add(_Sales);
                _SalesRepository.Save();
}
```

but when save is called, it gives me exception telling that unique key constraint is violated in db. the reason of this constraint being violated is previous record is not deleted from database and it simply wants to add another record on top of it. How can i solve this problem
regards

Answer (score 2):

So why don't call `_SalesRepository.Save();` before add new records ??

***Update:***

But isn't better to make Update instead of delete and add.
Just get the records and update them all using try catch then if everything OK do save.

Hope this helped

Comment: wouldn't it violate the transaction integrity. suppose we put save before Adding records and on adding record we find exception, wouldn't we be in an inconsistent state at db level

Comment: Then you should use Update instead of delete and add. Just get the records and update them all using `try catch` then if everything OK do save. Hope this helped :)

Comment: actually the record to be updated is master detail where in detail part user could have added some new records, deleted old records or done both of them. so, in this case, i believe adding the record after deleting makes more sense then checking for old records